# command is not getting executed, if started by service

Tags: linux, bash, services, java

I have a java programm with an update function. This function simply starts the jar and then stops itself. If i start the programm manually to test the update function, it works just fine. But if i start the programm with a service, it does not.
This is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts the Main Java Programm
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/sbin/start.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0
User=USERNAME

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This is start.sh (This way the programm does not restart itself):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/USERNAME/bin/java 

echo 'PASSWORD' | sudo -S java -jar variobox.jar > output.txt 2> error.txt
```

How i call the  programm manually (This is the way the programm restarts correctly):

```
echo 'PASSWORD' | sudo -S java -jar variobox.jar > output.txt 2> error.txt &
```

This is how the java programm updates itself:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "variobox.jar");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("output.txt"));
builder.redirectError(new File ("error.txt"));
builder.start();
```

The 2 txt files are completly empty after the programm should restart and i do not get any error message. It just does not restart. I think the problem is some kind of user/access restriction, with the service. But i am not far enough into linux to fully understand this. I thought by setting the user in the service and using `sudo` it should work.

**EDIT:** After changing `Type=simple` to `Type=forking` it works once. But after that it still does not restart.

Comment: Hint: `type=simple` is probably wrong. It should be `forking` as your script forks into a new process.

Comment: @Panki That actually did it. Do you want to write an answere or should i do it?

Comment: Feel free to do so if you want the rep

Comment: @Panki Correction: now it works once, but after that it still does not restart. But i really do not understand why it works if i start it manually